# Search an array of elements in a file and replace them with another array of elements -php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to

1. open and read a file,
2. Search a few words within the file,
3. Replace these words with some other words,
4. Put content into the file again.

The words for search and replace are taken dynamically from user input boxes. Here's the code I am going with,

```
$filename = 'test1.txt'; 
($handle = fopen($filename, 'r+')) or die(); 
$content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
echo $content.'<br>'.'<br>';

if (isset($_POST['findtext']) && isset($_POST['replacetext'])) {
$findtext = $_POST['findtext'];
$replacetext = $_POST['replacetext'];
if (!empty($findtext) && !empty('$replacetext')) {
    $ftxtarray = explode( ',', strtolower($findtext));
    $rtxtarray = explode(',', strtolower($replacetext));
    //  code?
    echo $content;
    } else {
    echo 'Please type in "Replace:" words and "Replace with:" words..';
    }

}
```

And the HTML,

```
<form action="firstfile.php" method="POST">
<br>Replace:<br>
<input type="text" name="findtext"><br>
Replace with:<br>
<input type="text" name="replacetext"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Lets say "test1.txt" contains few words including "John Doe" and user types in  "John,Doe" in the "Replace:" field and "Richard,Roe" in the "Replace with:" field.
Which method should I use to replace the specified words?

Comment: What's in `test.txt`? Can you skip that part (just put the contents in a string) and give a clear expected input and output example? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ggorlen       "test1.txt" is the file (residing in the same directory ) I am opening to check the specific words, ( which are taken from a input box) and if they exist, then they should be replaced with some other words.(also taken from another input box)

Comment: I realize that, but what's the content in that file? What's the expected input and output? What's wrong with your current code (e.g., what part of the process are you stuck on)? Did you read the MCVE? Your code is not valid PHP as it is written.

Comment: @ggorlen       I edited the question so it will be much clearer. I am not sure of the function which I'll have to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_replace()` and put in first parameter array of words to find, in second parameter array with the exact length as the first one, in third contents of a file loaded into variable, and you're good to go.